# How to get all nested collection details of root collection in Firestore?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

How can I get the value of `coursestatus` from all of the collections?

Comment: I don't see that collection in your attached screenshot?

Comment: The collection which is called `coursestatus` exists in a single document or in multiple documents? Can you show us a screenshot? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: No.. coursestatus is a variable, It will exist in all course completion documents @AlexMamo

Comment: So to understand better, the `CourseCompletion` sub-collection exists in multiple documents, right?

Comment: yes ofcourse @AlexMamo it exists in every

Answer (score 0):

See [Get all documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection)

You loop or iterate over it.

```
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "cities"));
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of `coursestatus` field which exists in multiple `CourseCompletion` sub-collections, then you have to perform a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

Comment: Hey Surya. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?